# Windows 10 VM ignores QXL video memory changes

Tags: linux-mint, windows, virtual-machine, qemu

[Linux Mint 19.3 host, UCA Stein PPA for QEMU v3, Windows 10 v2004 guest]

I'm trying to allocate more video RAM to my Windows 10 VM. I've always done this via **virsh**, changing these line:

```
<video>
    <model type='qxl' ram='262144' vram='262144' vgamem='65536' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</video>
```

These numbers are probably overkill for what I want to accomplish. When I check the graphics properties in the VM, I get this:

[image]

Other than seeming a little washed out, the video in the VM is OK, but it's only reading as 8-bit. What am I doing wrong? I have 6GB RAM set aside for the VM.

Comment: I also have problems with changing video RAM. When I edit the file using `sudo virsh edit` and save the file I will get this error: `error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng
Extra element devices in interleave`. So there is something fishy going on here.

Comment: I have since moved to LM 20, which comes with QEMU 4.2. I switched all of my systems to VirtIO video. I don't know my OP was fixed in QEMU 4.x as I don't run a Window VM anymore.

Comment: It looks like I edited the configuration in a wrong way. Here is hte solution to support 4K in QEMU: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1273106